# Como Graficar recorrido dada una matriz de manera dinámica Python

Tags: python

```
   maze = [
           ["[]","+","$","[]", "*"],
           ["[]","1","[]","[]","[]"],
           ["[]","[]","1","1","[]"],
           [0,"[]","[]","+","[]"],
           ]
```

esta matriz representa esta lo de esta imagen donde `0=inicio , []=espacio vacio , *=Meta, 1=espacios negros`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta matriz, es lo que me retorna el un codigo que ya tengo hecho que no tiene relevancia en la pregunta, es un codigo de busqueda en porfundidad, y esta es la matriz que me retorna donde los 0 son el recorrido que tuvo la mujer hasta llegar a la meta, que es el " * "

```
   matriz=[
           ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
           ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0'], 
           ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0'], 
           ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
          ]
```

mi cuestion es , leyendo esa matriz como hago para dibujar o graficar, o implementar alguna libreria que me grafique ese recorrido en una interfaz grafica ,y que quede algo parecido a esto
con o sin la animacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A tu pregunta le falta lo que haz logrado hacer hasta ahora. Si te doy una respuesta, estaría haciendo ese programa por ti. Sin embargo te doy una idea de lo que puedes usar para lograrlo. Puedes usar el [widget canvas](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas.html) del modulo de interfaz grafica Tkinter.

Comment: he logrado mostrar el tablero con pygame, y todo lo entiendo, pero mi dilema fue como dar la posiciones correspondientes a cada una de las imagenes, tambien vi lo de canvas pero el problemas fue lo mismo dar las posciones